# Dynamic rolling correlation excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, correlation, excel-indirect

I have a financial time series data set. I need to make a rolling window correlation, where I can control the window size, 1 dependent variable and 2 or more independent varaibles. And it needs to be dynamic when updating the data history. I also want to be able to choose the dependent.

I already managed to make the first dynamic correlation, where i changes as I change the constant of the window size

`="Data!"&ADRESS($A11;MATCH(B$7;TitleArray;0))&":"&ADRESS($B$1+ROW(Data!$A$1);MATCH(B$$7;TitleArray;0))`

The cell now holds an address to the range of the data in the window of the first variable

- Data is reffering to my data set.
- $A11 is my starting row number of the window. might need to relative?
- B$7 is a cell with the name of my dependent variable (I want to know how this corr with several other
  variables, but I need to be able shift between, which is the dependent one)
- TitleArray is name of a range holding the variable names
- $B$1 refers the the constant explaining the size of the window
- +ROW(Data!$A$1) makes sure that it adjusts when I add more history

Then I just copied this formula to the next cell in the column next to, replacing B7 with C7

Then, in a new cell I found the corr between the two in this way:

`CORRELATION(INDIRECT($o$16);INDIRECT(P16))`

Here I made the corr between the dependent and another variable for the set window (I tested it with 24 months).

Can anyone help me get the last steps in order to extend it to show the last corr windows for the remaining history? I suppose it should be rather easy, but I can't seem find the right way. I guess I have to remove some $ signs and then drag it down, but then I will get a lot of rows with adresses follows by correlations. Can it be made in a smarter way?

If any details are missing please let me know

thank you!

Comment: Is your formula correct or is it really like this: `="Data!"&ADDRESS($A11;MATCH(B$7;TitleArray;0))&":"&ADDRESS($B$1+ROW(Data!$A$1);MATCH(B$7;TitleArray;0))` ?  Also, if I understand it well, the correlation window size is really B1 + 1 - A11 (where 1 is really the row position of Data!A1)?  So, if B1 < A11 - 1, the range flips backwards.  Is that intentional?  In your approach, O16 and P16 are really helper cells to give you the ranges to correlate, if I understand well.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use OFFSET or INDEX, but I am not clear on what you want your end product to look like and what is really blocking you.  You would not need to do an INDIRECT on the ADDRESS results if you took this approach instead.  INDEX might be more tricky to use, but it would not be volatile whereas INDIRECT and OFFSET are.

Comment: Correct, I made a typo. It is B$7 and not b$$7.

Comment: Yes, O16 and P16 are cells where I have my formula, so this formula refer to the ranges to correlate. I am not sure I understand this: " Also, if I understand it well, the correlation window size is really B1 + 1 - A11 (where 1 is really the row position of Data!A1)? So, if B1 < A11 - 1, the range flips backwards"

If I use OFFSET I will just pick a cell and offset the value from that cell to another cell? So I'm not rolling my window?

Comment: Ahh - but OFFSET can pick an array as well.  The last two parameters show the row-size and column-size of the array.  So OFFSET(Data!A1; 0; 5; 24; 1 ) takes a 24 X 1 range (really, a column) of data starting at F1 - in other words F1:F24. e.g. If you did CORRELATION( OFFSET(Data!A1; 0; 5; 24; 1 ); OFFSET(Data!A1; 0; 6; 24; 1 ) ), you would be correlating F1:F24 with G1:G24.

Comment: When I drag it, it works for the columns, but the rows I get #I/T for two rows and then a correct result and then it continues with the same error #I/T

Comment: This is brilliant! I'm new to using these advanced functions, so this is interesting to learn. Which part of the formula makes sure that if I add more rows/history to the data, it will automatically adjust to that? 
I guess I can just keep B1 and delete the second part: ($B$1+2-$A$11), since it is just two constants (+2-2)?

Comment: I solved the drag problem. Rookie mistake using the wrong absolute referencing

Comment: Cool - I had a similar application some time ago, I built a "matrix" of time-series data - let's call it A, B, C, D... and I wanted to see the correlations between them over differing periods and durations.  I used OFFSET in a similar way with the CORREL( OFFSET A, OFFSET B) in one cell, then CORREL( OFFSET A, OFFSET C) in the cell below... to CORREL( OFFSET C, OFFSET D) so that all combinations were made. In the columns, I changed the window size or starting point. A kind of brute force multiple linear regression to discover the most paired factors.

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Btw, I ended up using the more complex method using adress, index and match functions, since it did, for some reason, not stop giving me new corr no matter the window, when I dragged it down. But I'm going to look at it one more time to see if I can solve the problem using offset. It seemed like a more simple way.
Thanks a lot for showing me the function anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hard to follow the specifics of your objectives, but here is an approach using OFFSET.

```
=CORRELATION( OFFSET( Data!$A$1; $A11-1; MATCH($B7;TitleArray;0 )-1; ($B$1+2-$A$11); 1 ); 
              OFFSET( Data!$A$1; $A11-1; MATCH(C7;TitleArray;0 )-1; ($B$1+2-$A$11); 1 ) )
```

B7 is the name of your dependent variable and C7 would be the independent variable name. As you drag this formula to the right, it would compare B7 to C7, then D7, etc.

NB: my OS is in English, so here is the working version in my machine just in case I errored in translation:

```
=CORREL( OFFSET( Data!$A$1, $A11-1, MATCH($B7,TitleArray,0 )-1, ($B$1+2-$A$11), 1 ), 
         OFFSET( Data!$A$1, $A11-1, MATCH(C7,TitleArray,0 )-1, ($B$1+2-$A$11), 1 ) )
```

With this approach, you can avoid having the helper cells with the formula:

```
="Data!"&ADDRESS($A11;MATCH(B$7;TitleArray;0))&":"&ADDRESS($B$1+ROW(Data!$A$1);MATCH(B$7;TitleArray;0))
```